# How to setup fast STM32 F4 FSMC to control a display on the STM32F4Discovery board?

Tags: microcontroller, clock, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm connecting an ILI9341 display controller to an STM32F407vg microcontroller (STM32 Discovery board). The display is connected to the STM32 with a 16-bit parallel databus.

To achieve high datarates I use the FSMC of the STM32. The FSMC is configured as a static RAM controller. I don't use chip select or read. The interface works, I can send data to the display, but it is slow.

I tried writing to the LCD with a for loop, but also with DMA in memory to memory mode. I tried writing data from flash, but also from RAM. Optimizing various DMA settings. All these changes didn't affect the speed at all. So to me there seems to be a huge bottleneck somewhere.

The figure below shows a measurement of a 16-bit word transfer (only the first 8 lines are measured). As you can see, the display's WR line toggles with only 558kHz.

[image: Logic analyzer FSMC 558kHz]

The figure below shows the FSMC timing as explained in the reference manual. `NWE` (write enable) is `WR` in my measurement. `A16` is `D/C`.
[image]

ADDSET and DATAST are in HCLK (AHB clock) cycles. The AHB clock is configured at its maximum speed of 168MHz. ADDSET and DATAST are set to 0 and 1. So I configured a speed of 84MHz. I don't expect to achieve 84MHz, because the DMA controller is slower (see below). But I would at least expect to achieve the DMA speed.

With ST's HAL v1.6.0.0 library I set the clock to the maximum speed:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

__HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

__HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                            |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

/* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}
```

I initialize FSMC:

```
void init_fsmc(void){
SRAM_HandleTypeDef sram_init_struct;
FSMC_NORSRAM_TimingTypeDef fsmc_norsram_timing_struct = {0};

sram_init_struct.Instance = FSMC_NORSRAM_DEVICE;
sram_init_struct.Extended = FSMC_NORSRAM_EXTENDED_DEVICE;

fsmc_norsram_timing_struct.AddressSetupTime       = 0;
fsmc_norsram_timing_struct.AddressHoldTime        = 1; // n/a for SRAM mode A
fsmc_norsram_timing_struct.DataSetupTime          = 1;
fsmc_norsram_timing_struct.BusTurnAroundDuration  = 0; 
fsmc_norsram_timing_struct.CLKDivision            = 2; // n/a for SRAM mode A
fsmc_norsram_timing_struct.DataLatency            = 2; // n/a for SRAM mode A
fsmc_norsram_timing_struct.AccessMode             = FSMC_ACCESS_MODE_A;

sram_init_struct.Init.NSBank             = FSMC_NORSRAM_BANK4;
sram_init_struct.Init.DataAddressMux     = FSMC_DATA_ADDRESS_MUX_DISABLE;
sram_init_struct.Init.MemoryType         = FSMC_MEMORY_TYPE_SRAM;
sram_init_struct.Init.MemoryDataWidth    = FSMC_NORSRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16;
sram_init_struct.Init.BurstAccessMode    = FSMC_BURST_ACCESS_MODE_DISABLE;
sram_init_struct.Init.WaitSignalPolarity = FSMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_POLARITY_LOW;
sram_init_struct.Init.WrapMode           = FSMC_WRAP_MODE_DISABLE;
sram_init_struct.Init.WaitSignalActive   = FSMC_WAIT_TIMING_BEFORE_WS;
sram_init_struct.Init.WriteOperation     = FSMC_WRITE_OPERATION_ENABLE;
sram_init_struct.Init.WaitSignal         = FSMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_DISABLE;
sram_init_struct.Init.ExtendedMode       = FSMC_EXTENDED_MODE_DISABLE; // maybe enable?
sram_init_struct.Init.AsynchronousWait   = FSMC_ASYNCHRONOUS_WAIT_DISABLE;
sram_init_struct.Init.WriteBurst         = FSMC_WRITE_BURST_DISABLE;

__HAL_RCC_FSMC_CLK_ENABLE();

HAL_SRAM_Init(&sram_init_struct, &fsmc_norsram_timing_struct, &fsmc_norsram_timing_struct);
}
```

I configure DMA:

```
void init_dma(void){
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*##-2- Select the DMA functional Parameters ###############################*/
  dma_handle.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
  dma_handle.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_MEMORY;
  dma_handle.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;               /* Peripheral increment mode */
  dma_handle.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_DISABLE;                  /* Memory increment mode */
  dma_handle.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD; /* Peripheral data alignment */
  dma_handle.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;    /* memory data alignment */
  dma_handle.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;                         /* Normal DMA mode */
  dma_handle.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;              /* priority level */
  dma_handle.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;           /* FIFO mode disabled */
  dma_handle.Init.FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;
  dma_handle.Init.MemBurst = DMA_MBURST_SINGLE;              /* Memory burst */
  dma_handle.Init.PeriphBurst = DMA_PBURST_SINGLE;           /* Peripheral burst */

  dma_handle.Instance = DMA2_Stream0;

  if(HAL_DMA_Init(&dma_handle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    // @todo proper error handling.
    return;
  }

  HAL_DMA_RegisterCallback(&dma_handle, HAL_DMA_XFER_CPLT_CB_ID, dma_transfer_complete);
  // @todo proper error handling
  HAL_DMA_RegisterCallback(&dma_handle, HAL_DMA_XFER_ERROR_CB_ID, dma_transfer_error);

  /*##-6- Configure NVIC for DMA transfer complete/error interrupts ##########*/
  /* Set Interrupt Group Priority */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 1, 0);

  /* Enable the DMA STREAM global Interrupt */
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);
}
```

And this is how I start the transaction:

```
HAL_DMA_Start_IT(&dma_handle, (uint32_t)&data_buffer, (uint32_t)&LCD_RAM, pixelCount);
```

When I perform a DMA transfer from SRAM1 to SRAM2 with this DMA configuration, I achieve a transferspeed of ~38MHz. So this is the speed I would expect on the FSMC.

What is holding back the FSMC?

Comment: You say that it's "slow", and show us an image with a few numbers. What is those 558kHz supposed to signify? RAM write rate? RAM read rate? Display refresh rate? Something else? And what numbers did you expect? When you write something to your screen, does it refresh slow? The more details you can give us, the easier it will become to help you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is limiting the FSMC timing settings, and what frequency you would expect them to yield? I have no knowledge of the peripheral but they rather stand out.

Comment: You should maybe use a microcontroller with TFT controller such as STM32F437, it would simplify your life.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I have updated my question.

Comment: @doynax Thanks, I have updated my question.

Comment: @Guillaume Michel Maybe it would simplify my life, maybe I would run into the same issue, but then with the LCD peripheral.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `dma_handle.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;`?

Comment: @GuillaumeMichel Well spotted. The quoted code is for a single color fill. If I transmit a bitmap, I enable PeriphInc (SRAM is the peripheral and FSMC the memory in my config).

Comment: @i.amniels: Well, you do seem to be losing 300-odd cycles _somewhere_. I rather fear this is the sort of thing where you'll end up scouring the footnotes of the datasheet and experimenting with various settings to see how they determine the timing. Personally I'd start by dumping the physical register states after the initialization, to insure that the helper functions did their work as expected. I would also try to dig up working sample code and demo boards, even if targetting other bus devices, and try to carefully "narrow the gap" between the set-ups.

Comment: @i.amniels Could you add to your question what speed you would expect to obtain?

Comment: @staringlizard It is in the question. I think DMA should be the bottleneck and DMA can achieve 38MHz, so this is the speed I expect on FSMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very short piece of code [here](http://www.chibios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=471#p4244) which shows how to configure FSMC with only CMSIS.

With one line of HAL code to activate the clock, this piece of code looks like this:

```
__HAL_RCC_FSMC_CLK_ENABLE();

int FSMC_Bank = 0;
FSMC_Bank1->BTCR[FSMC_Bank+1] = FSMC_BTR1_ADDSET_1 | FSMC_BTR1_DATAST_1;

// Bank1 NOR/SRAM control register configuration
FSMC_Bank1->BTCR[FSMC_Bank] = FSMC_BCR1_MWID_0 | FSMC_BCR1_WREN | FSMC_BCR1_MBKEN;
```

I tried this code and now I achieve a speed of ~27MHz. This is in the range of what I expected.

For now I will continue using this code, the root cause analysis is something for later.

BTW If you use FSMC on the STM32F4 Discovery board, desolder resistor R50, because it is connected to FSMC's NWE pin and the circuit which is connected to the STM32 with this 0 Ohm resistor has a pull-up which will distort the transfers.

Answer (score 0):

```
"sram_init_struct.Init.NSBank             = FSMC_NORSRAM_BANK4"
```

The bank number may be wrong, you can try using the FSMC_NORSRAM_BANK1 replace FSMC_NORSRAM_BANK4.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use HSE instead of HSI :

```
  /* Enable HSE Oscillator and activate PLL with HSE as source */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8; // 8MHz crystal frequency
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336; // 2*168, 168MHz PLL_Freq
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);
```

Regards

Comment: can you please elaborate on how HSE is a better fit than HSI ?

Comment: Ouch ! You're right, I just made a calculation error because I used wrong PLL parameters ! So, I found low frequencies on buses that would impact FSMC performances. Sorry. :)